# JavaScript: Object.prototype.toString(new Number(5)) seems to return a wrong type

Tags: javascript, internal

I am writing JavaScript interpreter in Python and I have to understand internals. Consider this code (tested on V8):

```
Object.prototype.toString(new Number(5)) //gives "[object Object]"
```

According to the [specification of Number constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.2.1):

*"The [[Class]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to "Number"."*

And [Object.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) returns the combination of:

```
"[object ", class, and "]" // where class is the value of [Class]] internal property of O.
```

Therefore why the returned value is `"[object Object]"` instead of `"[object Number]"`? Is it a bug in V8 or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: toString doesn't take an argument, are you meaning to do `Object.prototype.toString.call(new Number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toString` doesn't take an argument -- it's a *method* on the object.  So if you call 
`Object.prototype.toString.call(new Number(5))` (thus passing the Number instance as `this`) you'll get the expected result: `[object Number]`.

You get similarly bogus results when calling `SomeClass.prototype.toString` with an argument, for example `Number.prototype.toString(new Number(5))` will give `'0'`.

I tested all of this on node (which uses v8).

Comment: Oh of course I am sorry, I spent an hour trying to figure out whats wrong with my understanding and it turned out to be just a careless mistake.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)